# How can I create a page that can be slided from the bottom of the screen in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, layout, dart

How can I create a page that slides from the bottom of the screen and when it passes a certain threshold automatically fills the screen? 
Something like this:

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Consider using [DraggableScrollableSheet](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/DraggableScrollableSheet-class.html) class or [sliding up panel](https://pub.dev/packages/sliding_up_panel) package

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You can use `PageRouteBuilder` to build your own navigator transitions.

This is the `CustomPageRouteBuilder` class as you need, and you can change it into other transitons like `scale` `fade` `rotate`, etc.

```dart
class CustomPageRouteBuilder<T> extends PageRouteBuilder<T> {

  CustomPageRouteBuilder({
    this.widget,
  })
    : assert(widget != null),
      super(
        pageBuilder: (BuildContext context, Animation<double> animation, Animation<double> secondaryAnimation) {
          return widget;
        },
        transitionsBuilder: (BuildContext context, Animation<double> animation, Animation<double> secondaryAnimation, Widget child) {
          final Widget transition = SlideTransition(
            position: Tween<Offset>(
              begin: Offset(0.0, 1.0),
              end: Offset.zero,
            ).animate(animation),
            child: SlideTransition(
              position: Tween<Offset>(
                begin: Offset.zero,
                end: Offset(0.0, -0.7),
              ).animate(secondaryAnimation),
              child: child,
            ),
          );

          return transition;
        },
      );

  final Widget widget;

}
```

And how to use:

```dart
Navigator.push(
  context,
  CustomPageRouteBuilder(
    widget: SecondPage(),
  ),
);
```

You can check the sample below:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: FirstPage(),
    );
  }
}

class FirstPage extends StatelessWidget {

  const FirstPage({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        color: Colors.red,
        child: Center(
          child: Text(
            'First Page',
            style: TextStyle(
              color: Colors.white,
              fontSize: 24.0,
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        child: Icon(
          Icons.arrow_forward_ios,
          color: Colors.white,
        ),
        onPressed: () {
          Navigator.push(
            context,
            CustomPageRouteBuilder(
              widget: SecondPage(),
            ),
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }

}

class SecondPage extends StatelessWidget {

  const SecondPage({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        color: Colors.blue,
        child: Center(
          child: Text(
            'Second Page',
            style: TextStyle(
              color: Colors.white,
              fontSize: 24.0,
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        child: Icon(
          Icons.arrow_back_ios,
          color: Colors.white,
        ),
        onPressed: () {
          Navigator.pop(context);
        },
      ),
    );
  }

}

class CustomPageRouteBuilder<T> extends PageRouteBuilder<T> {

  CustomPageRouteBuilder({
    this.widget,
  })
    : assert(widget != null),
      super(
        pageBuilder: (BuildContext context, Animation<double> animation, Animation<double> secondaryAnimation) {
          return widget;
        },
        transitionsBuilder: (BuildContext context, Animation<double> animation, Animation<double> secondaryAnimation, Widget child) {
          final Widget transition = SlideTransition(
            position: Tween<Offset>(
              begin: Offset(0.0, 1.0),
              end: Offset.zero,
            ).animate(animation),
            child: SlideTransition(
              position: Tween<Offset>(
                begin: Offset.zero,
                end: Offset(0.0, -0.7),
              ).animate(secondaryAnimation),
              child: child,
            ),
          );

          return transition;
        },
      );

  final Widget widget;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend the `PageView` widget, you can see more [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=J1gE9xvph-A) and [view the documentation](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/PageView-class.html).

Using the `scrollDirection` property, you can set it to vertical so that you can swipe up to reveal a new page and you can swipe down to go back.